# alcohol, stability, experience

Tags: technique, darts

Last night I went to a local bar and had a few dart matches with my friends. It was an enjoyable night for sure.

The first two matches were 701 games, and my performance was just as usual with an average PPR around 50. However, after consuming more and more alcohol, I couldn't keep my hand steady. I just missed all the targets I aimed at, especially during the Cricket matches played afterwards. My MPR dropped from 1.8 to somewhere below 1.0. The phenomenon found on myself could be concluded as **drink more, miss more**.

I would like to know if this is a common thing among dart players. Since I have seen players still played very well after drinking quite a lot of beer, I wonder whether this is related to darting experiences.

By the way, is there any way to improve such **drink more, miss more** situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your experienced in the bar of an initial improvement, then a decline, has also been [studied](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8367248) in a controlled environment. Researchers T. Reilly and J. Scott summarized their study as follows:

> Light (0.02% BAC) and moderate (0.05% BAC) does of alcohol were
>   administered to 10 dart throwers while effects were monitored on tasks
>   related to dart throwing, i.e., rotary pursuit and hand steadiness.
>   Balance and accuracy of throwing improved with the 0.02% BAC, but
>   performance was impaired with 0.05% BAC. The higher BAC levels were
>   linked with deteriorations on rotary pursuit and hand steadiness.

So for optimal performance, you need to keep your alcohol level fairly low but non-zero.
The blood alcohol level [depends on a lot of factors:](http://www.alcoholalert.com/blood-alcohol-level.html), including:

- The presence of food in your stomach
- Number of drinks per hour.
- Tolerance to alcohol, or learned tolerance
- Weight
- Gender

One solution would be to drink 1-2 beers (or whatever you need to get to about 0.02 % BAC), then switch to non-alcoholic drinks, and have another beer or two when you finish playing.

If you want to keep drinking, and keep playing darts well after the first couple of beers, you will need to eat something in the bar (crisps are traditional), consume alcohol regularly, and put on some weight. You may notice that drinking regularly and eating crisps are a quick and easy way to put on weight. This may answer the question posed, but also bring health risks, so I personally wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Great answer with cool scientific evidence! Thanks for your information. FYI, I drank two glasses of Mojito in one and a half hour. Was it too much?